# Is EF Core an Implementation of the Data Mapper or Active Record Patterns?

Tags: entity-framework-core, architecture

Can someone clarify if Microsoft Entity Framework Core implements the Data Mapper or Active Record patterns? I can't find in the framework documentation a place where the strategies followed by the framework are explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that two main patterns which should considered when talking about Entity Framework are [Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design) (via `DbSet<T>`) and [Unit of Work](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) (via `DbContext`). EF definitely is not an Active Record and I would say it can be considered as Data Mapper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Greg Burghardt said in another channel: "I don't imagine it is an implementation of Active Record, because the entities themselves are not responsible for their own persistence. You can scratch Active Record from the list." Now I have a better idea of where to find answers.