# FindAsync make problen when send query in database in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to use a generic repository for CRUD and this is my interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    void Insert(T obj);
    void Update(T obj);
    void Delete(object id);
    Task SaveAsync();
}
```

And this is my repo

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;  
using Sirjan.Models;

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class  
{
    public SirjanContext? _context = null;
    public DbSet<T>? table = null;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        this._context = new SirjanContext();
        table = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public GenericRepository(SirjanContext _context)
    {
        this._context = new SirjanContext();
        table = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await table!.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        var item = await table.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id = id);
        if(item == null)
        return null;            
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table!.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        table!.Attach(obj);
        _context!.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = table!.Find(id)!;
        table.Remove(existing);
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
       await _context!.SaveChangesAsync();
    } 
}
```

In my repo when I use

```
 var item = await table.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id);
```

I got an error that:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm using a relational database, this query must retrieve from another table that has *one to many* relation.

Also this code because of relational table doesn't work.

```
 var item = await table.Find(id);
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `T` can be *any* class. You can't expect any class to have an `Id` property.

Comment: What are your models? Do you have a  common model base that you can use for the generic constraint?

Comment: @gert-arnold Ok I undrestand, what can i do? Do I have to create a base model class that has a property with the name of Id?

Answer (score 0):

`T` can be any class which is not guaranteed to have an Id. Usual approach in such cases is to introduce an interface (or a base class) which will define this property and restrict `T` to it:

```cs
public interface IHaveId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IHaveId
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the code, but my "shafafItem" table has relation to the parrent table that is "ShafahCategory" table, In non-generic repository I would add '.include' to query and it worked but in generic repository how can I handle that?

Comment: @sunny you need either provide additional parameter to the corresponding method or override it in the generic repo inheritor. Note that there are quite a lot of people who consider using generic repo over EF Core to be an antipattern because EF Core already implements repo ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247844/2501279)).